# Property on path-components

Tags: general-topology

Let $a=(a_1,\dots, a_k)$ and $b=(b_1,\dots, b_k)$ be points in $k$-dimentional space $\mathbb{R}^k$. A $\textit{path}$ from $a$ to $b$ is a continuous function on the unit interval $[0,1]$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^k$, a function $X: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$, sending $t \mapsto X(t)=(x_1(t),\dots, x_k(t))$, such that $X(0)=a$ and $X(1)=b.$ If $S$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and if $a$ and $b$ are in $S$, define $a \sim b$ if $a$ and $b$ can be joined by a path lying entirely in $S$.

How do I show that two points in different subsets cannot be connected by a path in $S$?

Comment: What do you mean by "two points in different subsets"? Which different subsets? Certainly there are points which can be contained in different (even disjoint) subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but are still connected by a path in $S$.

Comment: @MattPressland two different subset of S (path components)

Comment: @Carpediem Not every subset is a path component, and it wasn't clear they should be subsets of $S$, hence my request for clarification. I'm still a little confused; if you replace "subsets" by "path components of $S$", then there's essentially nothing to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $a,b\in S$ and suppose that $a$ and $b$ are not in the same path component. Then $a$ and $b$ are not in the same $\sim$-equivalence class and so if there existed a path in $S$ from $a$ to $b$ then we would have a contradiction as it would imply that $a\sim b$ and so $a$ and $b$ are in the same $\sim$ equivalence class. Hence there is no path in $S$ connecting $a$ and $b$.